# Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program when using const string as optional parameter

Tags: c#

I am getting `System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program` in a assembly which has a extension method defined like below.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public const string DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss";

    public static string ToStorageString(this DateTime value, string format = DATE_TIME_FORMAT)
    {
        return value.ToString(format ?? DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
    }
}
```

But if I change extension method to just use string literal instead then the exception doesn't happen, example below.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static readonly string DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss";

    public static string ToStorageString(this DateTime value, string format = "MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    {
        return value.ToString(format ?? DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
    }
}
```

I am compiling the assembly against .net 4.6.2

I am not sure why the exception is occurring with the first code, can anyone explain?

Comment: Works on my box. Can you give us any details of your environment?  Are you using VS? What version? Updates? etc.?

Comment: @MattJohnson Built using VS2015 Update 3. Works fine in debug mode. Tried the application on Windows 8.1, Windows 10 and Windows 7, same error.